# SQLite database access through Eclipse

Tags: database, sqlite

How to check if the data is saved or not in SQLite database?
I am accessing SQLite database through eclipse and there is no error while writing data in the database. Bus While retriving the records, no record is returned.

So please suggest me how can I access the data in SQLite database?